# Add HashMap into list then add generated list to new HashMap using a lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have the below code, which works fine.
In this code, its adding an element in LinkedHashMap, this Map is then added to a new list, and finally, that list is added into another LinkedHashMap.
I am trying to find a better short way using java8 to make it more simple and short, any suggestion?

```
private Object getData() {
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> secondLevelMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        secondLevelMap.put("href", "http://SomeLink");
        List<LinkedHashMap> firstLevelList = new ArrayList<>(2);
        firstLevelList.add(null);
        firstLevelList.add(secondLevelMap);
        LinkedHashMap<String, List<LinkedHashMap>> firstLevelMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        firstLevelMap.put("links", firstLevelList);
        return firstLevelMap;
    }
```

Comment: It looks OK to me, although I'd make the observation you should be returning some  thing more specific then Object, and  `List<LinkedHashMap` should probably reduced to `List<Map>`. In later version of Java you have `list.of()` which might be helpful (although it is null hostile)

Comment: why `LinkedHashMap` if you have single element inside? this sounds like [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: This does not look okay to me, since *raw types* are used. You shouldn't use them, instead, provide all necessary type arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Here a couple of helper methods could be implemented to create a map using a `Supplier<Map>`, populate it with a default key-value and return the map.

As for list, there is method `Arrays.asList` to create a list from object(s), which may be used as is if a fixed-size list is fine, or can be wrapped into `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(...))` to create a fully mutable list.

```java
private static <K, V> Map<K, V> createMap(K key, V value) {
    return createMap(key, value, LinkedHashMap::new);
}

private static <K, V> Map<K, V> createMap(K key, V value, Supplier<Map<K, V>> mapSupplier) {
    Map<K, V> map = mapSupplier.get();
    map.put(key, value);

    return map;
}
```

Then `getData` may be rewritten as follows (also, fixed the raw `Object` in return type):

```java
public Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> getData() {
    return createMap("links", new ArrayList<>(
            Arrays.asList(null, createMap("href", "http://SomeLink"))
    ));
}
```

Test

```
System.out.println(new MyClass().getData());
```

Output:

```
{links=[null, {href=http://SomeLink}]}
```

---

For exercise purpose, a couple of "lambdas" may be defined to refer `createMap` method with specific type of arguments:

```java
BiFunction<String, String, Map<String, String>> innerMapSupplier = (k, v) -> MyClass.createMap(k, v);
BiFunction<String, List<Map<String, String>>, Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>> resultMapSupplier = (k, v) -> MyClass.createMap(k, v);

System.out.println(
    resultMapSupplier.apply("links", Arrays.asList(
        null, 
        innerMapSupplier.apply("href", "http://SomeLink")
    ))
);
```